# How can I set a full variable constant?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

When the number size is variable and thus must be set by parameter, how can I set the maximum number? In the following, the result must be "FFFF", but the simulator returns just "F". Could anyone fix this problem?

```
`define SIZE 10
module tb1;
    reg [15:0] a;

    initial begin
        a = `SIZE'hF;
        $display("a=%h",a);
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the replication operator to construct bit vectors.

**{a{b}}** produces a vector with **a** copies of vector **b**.

In your case this would be:

```
 a = {`SIZE{1'b1}};
```

Comment: Using replication, the SIZE must be set to 16. Maybe it is a typo in his code. {10{1'b1}} results in 03FF only. The get the maximum number of `a`, either to change `SIZE` to 16 or using unsized single-bit value.

Answer (score 5):

`` `SIZE'hF ``, the `SIZE` part only means it is a n-bit width number only. In your case `10'hF` means it is a 10-bit number `0xF`, so it is correct in your simulation.

If you are using SystemVerilog, you can just use `a = '1;` and it will set all bits to 1.

Here is what SystemVerilog LRM says,

> An unsized single-bit value can be specified by preceding the single-bit value with an apostrophe ( ' ), but without the base specifier. All bits of the unsized value shall be set to the value of the specified bit. In a self-determined context, an unsized single-bit value shall have a width of 1 bit, and the value shall be treated as unsigned.